# Homemade mac and cheese always loses its creaminess and gets dry after sitting out a short while

Tags: sauce, cheese, pasta

How do I keep the pasta from absorbing all the liquid?

Comment: What's your recipe? It's hard to make suggestions for adjustments if we don't know what you're already doing :)

Answer (score 7):

Honestly, you either eat it fresh, or accept it will congeal.

There are 2 factors going on,

1. the pasts will keep absorbing water until there's almost none left
2. the cheese will set as it cools.

The upside is 'yesterday's mac cheese' is great in & of itself.

Your only 'fix' is make it wetter or eat it sooner.

Answer (score 1):

There are different styles of mac & cheese. One of my favorites is essentially just a béchamel sauce + cheese poured over cooked noodles.

You can eliminate the described problem completely by not incorporating the sauce and the noodles until it is time to eat. If cooked noodles sit around they will clump up if left to their own devices, so you will have to solve that new problem but it’s not insurmountable.

Answer (score 0):

**Try tossing cooked pasta in butter first, before adding cheese sauce.**

The idea is that the pasta acquires a hydrophobic oil coating that limits its access to the water part of the cheese sauce.  Also, if it doesn't work, it will still be delicious!

Tossing the pasta in oil or butter seems to help pasta salad.  Not sure about mac and cheese because it goes so quick around here.